# ReSharper and auto closing parentheses

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, resharper-5.0

Is there a way to avoid closing the following parentheses:

`String.Format(`**`)`**, or `Console.WriteLine(`**`)`** automatically?

Sometimes is this is annoying and unnecessary, and I end up pressing `Delete` to remove it.

I tried disabling `Auto-insert pair brackets, pharentheses and quotes`
and `Auto-insert closing brace` and it is still not working...

Comment: I felt annoying at the start but now I am so used to the auto close that I never end up using the close braces!

Comment: @Vinod R In fact, I enjoy it, but sometimes it just crashes the code (in more than one scenario)

Comment: I'm surprised it's not working for you.  I just tried it here.  Can you elaborate on precisely what you do?  (Also, 5.1 has been out for some time -- perhaps you're experiencing a bug that has since been fixed?  Current version is 5.1.3)

Comment: @Kirk I'm not sure about what I need to elaborate. I turned off those two features, restarted VS and the same parentheses are still being closed. I will take a look at the changelogs at JetBrains site...

Answer (score 45):

The following options should be unchecked/checked in `Resharper` if you do not want autocomplete feature on parenthesis (all options can be accessed through *Visual Studio > ReSharper > Options... > Environment*)

**To disable parenthesis auto insert in non method calls** (as pointed out in the question, you have already disabled it)

- Editor > Auto-insert pair brackets, pharentheses and quotes (unchecked)
- Editor > Auto-insert closing brace (unchecked)

**To disable parenthesis auto insert in method calls**

- Intellisense > Completion Behavior > Automatically insert parenthesis after completion > Opening only (enabled)

  [image: Automatically insert parenthesis after completion]

Tested in `Visual Studio 2008` with `ReSharper 6.0`.

Comment: This does not work for when i type "new InvalidOperationException" it auto completes with opening and closing parenthesis. Your answer only fixes it for methods not for class constructors or attributes.

Comment: @JDPeckham, I have checked the second option in VS2010 + Resharper 6. Works as expected for class constructor calls i.e. inserts the opening braces only.

Comment: Seems to be a bug with opening only. When I able this option, it still adds the closing. I had to disable it completely.

Comment: Worth noting that once you've stopped R# doing it, you'll then need to stop Studio itself doing it as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055800/how-to-turn-off-brackets-quotes-auto-completion-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 4):

In Resharper 9.2, I had the same items unchecked as given in Devendra's answer, but still experienced lag when typing parentheses and brackets.

I found that these issues went away by setting `Do not complete on` values as found in **Resharper >> Options > Environment > IntelliSense > Completing Characters**. In the Dialog pane that appears, I set the `Do not complete on` field to `(){}.` for C# and JavaScript.