# My Brackets Will Not Autocomplete In Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide, brackets

Whenever I type an opening bracket (square, curly, parentheses or otherwise), I am used to having its closing pair automatically generated by the compiler. At least, this was the case in my previous compiler. However, this doesn't happen for me in Visual Studio 2012. I've looked around in the options a bit, under Tools > Options > Text Editor > C++, but I can't seem to find an option to change this.

Can anyone suggest anything? Surely I am able to turn this feature on?

Comment: Mine all seem to do that, so at least there's a way.

Comment: dupe of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055800/how-to-turn-off-brackets-quotes-auto-completion

Comment: That guy wants to turn his off, but mine aren't even on in the first place. Also, he's using the C# version of the IDE, which may or may not be subtly different?

Answer (score 1):

Open your block, say :

```
void foo()
{
```

then hit `Tab`.
I've been wondering this myself for some time and found it just today.

But I don't know if it is possible to have automatic `()` or `[]`.

Comment: It must be. All of the closing ones of these appear when I open mine. For functions, it's as simple as pressing enter: `void foo {|` auto--> `void foo() {|}` enter--> `void foo() {\n|\n}` Unfortunately, I'm not exactly sure what's doing it.

Comment: Ahh, well, at least it works for the time being! Disappointed I can't figure out how to make Enter do the same, but that will do. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

A problem that I ran into for Visual Studio 2015 is that if there was an unbalanced bracket anywhere in the current file aka:

```
while(foo) {
    if(bar) {
}
```

then bracket autocompletion assumed that I was making a code block which was more deeply nested, which led to some odd behavior. If somewhere else in the file I tried to press enter to go from this (where the text cursor is represented by the pipe character( | ):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {|
```

to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    |
}
```

I would instead get this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    |
```

So if your autocompletion isn't working in a single file, maybe check whether the braces in your file are balanced.