# Brace auto formatting on separate lines

Tags: c#, coding-style, visual-studio-2015, code-formatting

If I enter some simple code such as:

```
public void Hello()
```

and then press enter and type a `{`, I get:

```
public void Hello()
{ }
```

I would like the result to be either:

```
public void Hello()
{                   // no added '}'
```

or:

```
public void Hello()
{
}                   // the '}' on a new line
```

I've looked around `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style` and `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting` but cannot seem to find how to make the above changes.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055800/how-to-turn-off-brackets-quotes-auto-completion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Productivity Tools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d)

Auto brace completion is one of the many features it has to offer