# VS Code Editor does not close double quotes

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 13 Ultimate Edition. When I type opening double quotes (")  in visual basic, it won't automatically add the closing quotes.

E.g. I type this

```
Console.WriteLine(")
```

and after typing opening quotes, I want it to add the closing quotes like this

```
Console.WriteLine(" ")
```

but it doesn't happen.

Comment: heay i am asking different and u are ansring diff

Comment: This is not a duplicate. OP is asking about Visual Studio Ultimate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055800/how-to-turn-off-brackets-quotes-auto-completion-in-visual-studio is about VS Code. The confusion is in the title, which means "Visual Studio" "Code Editor", not "Visual Studio Code" "Editor". His labels are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `Automatic brace completion` is checked in the menu `Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic`.

Also, [Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace) VS extension might be needed.

Comment: it is turned on but still not working...!!!

Comment: And what about braces/parenthesis, are they automatically closed?

Comment: braces/parenthesis are working but double quots in visual basic not working