# move out of closing brace in visual studio shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, shortcut

I am new to visual studio. Everytime I open a brace in visual studio the IDE automatically closes the brace.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int j = 2 * i; // My cursor is here right now
}
// I want my cursor here without pressing down arrow key
```

I don't want to press down arrow key every time I want to move out of the block. Is there any shortcut for that in visual studio. I know I can turn off this feature.

Edit 1 : I don't know why this question is marked as duplicate. In fact, the "original" question is completely different than mine. The "original" question asks how to go from opening brace to closing brace and vice versa.

Comment: Check the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055800/how-to-turn-off-brackets-quotes-auto-completion)

Comment: @JimHewitt The link mentioned only describes the steps to turn off the feature. I know I can turn off this feature. I want to know if there is a shortcut (to jump out of the block). Am I missing something in the link you mentioned ?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I missed the last part of your question

Comment: Does ctrl+] do something different than what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Pressing `}` gets me out of the block.