# Is it possible to disable automatic constructor completion?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

- I already have [Automatic brace completion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22359789) disabled. That's not the issue here.
- I have a nested class `Outer.Inner`.
- Normally when I type `out.` it auto-completes to `Outer.` and brings up another intellisense list with `Inner` in it.
- But if I type `new out.` it auto-completes to `new Outer().`, which is really unhelpful. Even more so since the `Outer` class doesn't even have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Do you really commonly have situations where nested classes are being referenced from *outside* of the class they're nested in? That would seem an unusual setup. Most of the time they're only referenced from within the outer class itself in which case the outer name isn't required.

Comment: Whaich version of visual studio you are using?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes I do. A lot of them in fact. But we're not here to argue the benefits of my coding style. If you're interested in my reasoning, we can discuss it elsewhere.

Comment: @Harkiratsingh Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.10.1.

Comment: Are you using ReSharper, or only vanilla visual studio?

Comment: @RandRandom I have some extensions, but no ReSharper and nothing else that looks like it should cause this behaviour.

Comment: Was asking since I installed Visual Studio 2022 recently which has no extension, and everything still default, and I don't get the described behaviour. It only writes `Outer` without the `()` when I hit tab or enter, after I typed `var x = new Out`

Comment: I agree, we're not here to discuss your coding style, but please realise that nested classes (somewhat rare), accessed externally (quite rare) and *constructed* externally (very rare), **and** where construction of the outer class doesn't occur is probably not on anyone's radar, let alone they provide an option to prevent it.

Comment: And you have to compare that necessary analysis vs a simple type vs namespace check when `.` is hit.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable `Edit/Intellisense/Switch between automatic and tab-only IntelliSense completion`.
[image]

Comment: Avoiding this one small annoyance isn't worth disabling automatic completion for everything else.

Comment: Visual studio cannot disable it for single situation currently. If you need it, you can provide a suggestion here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion

Comment: Yep, I did: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/automatic-constructor-completion-is-unhelpful/1460935