# How to disable automatic parentheses in new statement in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, the language is C#.

I have such a class and its nested class like this:

```
class Peer
{
    public class ServerCommandQuit {}
    public Peer(int id) {}
}
```

To construct an instance of `Peer.ServerCommandQuit` I will type:

```
new Peer.ServerCommandQuit();
        ^
```

The problem is when I press the dot `.` key, Visual Studio will automatically append a pair of parentheses after the outer class name:

```
new Peer().
```

How can I disable this feature? I have tried to uncheck **Automatic brace completion** and all 4 options in **IntelliCode**.

Comment: What happens when you keep typing? (suggestions are shown in grey and will disappear when you keep typing something else)

Comment: The parentheses are not suggestions, they are actually inserted. When I keep typing they remain. And I can see the red wavy underline under **Peer** because it doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: That's annoying. Pressing tab after typing `Peer` stops the parentheses from turning up but I can't see a way to switch that feature off completely.

Comment: Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68128803/is-it-possible-to-disable-automatic-constructor-completion) question

Comment: There's a pull request in the Roslyn project [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/63015)

Comment: Thanks @Yitz, the tab key helps, I am disappointed to hear that the problem has not been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After typing peer, press esc and then type "." the brackets will not appear.

The method in [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68128803/is-it-possible-to-disable-automatic-constructor-completion) provided by Yitz can also solve this problem:

[image]