# Visual Studio Intellicode does not add closing curly brace

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, intellicode

When I use AI-assisted IntelliCode in Visual Studio 2022, I want that Visual Studio also inserts the closing curly brace - not only the opening one. The cursor should then be between the brackets.

[image]

Does anyone know if this can be configured somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option **Automatic brace completion**, in `Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > General > Automatic brace completion`

The setting can also be enabled per language if you want that set only for a specific language.

Reference:
[How to turn off brackets/quotes auto-completion in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055800/how-to-turn-off-brackets-quotes-auto-completion-in-visual-studio)